# How to show that (-√2,√2)$\cap$Q is closed and bounded subset of Q ; but not compact?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

How to show that (-√2,√2)$\cap$Q is closed and bounded subset of Q ; but not compact.

The part that given set is bounded is clear. How to show that it is closed in Q. Now let G=(-√2,√2)$\cap$Q. Then G is closed in Q if and only if G=Q$\cap$W where W is a closed set in R but i can't think of any W. How to show that G is not compact in Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1:**  $(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}) \cap \mathbb Q = [-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}] \cap \mathbb Q$.

**Hint 2** Show that if $a_n \in (-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}) \cap \mathbb Q$ is so that $a_n \to \sqrt{2}$ then $(-a_n,a_n)$ is an open cover for this set.